# Moment generating function for the sum

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Let $r_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be 
Rademacher random variables, i.e. taking values $\pm1$ with probability $\frac 12$ and such that deference of them is equal to $
D$.
Let $x_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be real numbers.

Let $\pi$ be a permutation of the index-set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$
Consider $S=\sum_{i=1}^kr_ix_{\pi(i)}, k<n$.

How to find a moment generating function for $S$?

Comment: Are the $r_i$'s independent?

Comment: Not nececerelly. Lets suppose that they are dependent, say difference of them is $D$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the difference of them"?

Comment: I mean, $r_1-r_2-\ldots-r_n=D$

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So is $D$ a fixed constant, e.g., $0$, $1$? So you are conditioning on $r_1 - r_2 -\cdots-r_n=D$? (That's a little unusual, I think.) And $\pi$ is some given, fixed, permutation, is that right?